# How to use ignorecase and startsWith simultaneously on string java

Tags: java

I want to use `startsWith()` and `equalIgnoreCase` simultaneously on a string in java. How can I do that?

Comment: Its easy and possible. Show your code.

Comment: And just for the record: watch your wording the next time. We don't follow orders here; so "tell me how to use it" is actually a no go.

Comment: Hi, please take time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This will help others and you to get answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

The point is: both of these methods return a **boolean** result. They give you a yes/no information about the string you invoke them on. So you can't call them "simultaneously". You have to step back and re-think what you intend to achieve ...

So, what you are **looking** for is probably:

```
if ("someString".toLowerCase().startsWith("bla")) {
```

(and just for the record: doing something like that is actually good practice; like when asking the user for his input, you want to treat "Yes", "yes", "YEs" all the same.

In that sense, calling `toLowerCase()` can be seen as "normalization" step on your input data.

Answer (score 0):

[GhostCat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43466500/3788176) may well be fine for your use case, but it is that it is inefficient for large test strings, because `toLowerCase()` will create a copy of the string you want to check, most of which you won't care about.

But you don't need to create a copy of the string at all. `String` has a method called [`regionMatches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-boolean-int-java.lang.String-int-int-), which allows you to test whether *parts* of two strings match, optionally ignoring the case. (Actually, this is used in `equalsIgnoreCase`)

```
if (input.regionMatches(true, 0, prefix, 0, prefix.length()))) {
  // ...
}
```

If you are doing this in more than a couple of of places, I would write a short helper method to hide most of the parameters, so you can call it like:

```
if (startsWithIgnoreCase(input, prefix)) {
  // ...
}
```